# DJI SDK 4.5.1 release version crash

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-proguard, dji-sdk

Im creating an android application to control DJI Drones.
I just updated to DJI SDK 4.5.1, the application is working as intended when I have the build variant set to 'Debug'.
When I change to 'Release' version with 'minifyEnabled' to 'true' and a proguard file the application crashes just after the permissions have been set.
If I change 'minifyEnabled' to 'false' then the application runs without any errors.

The application worked just fine prior to the SDK 4.5.1 update (with 'minifyEnabled' to 'true')

I checked if DJI's Mobile SDK tutorials (https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-GEODemo) have the same problem, and the same error occurs when I change minifyEnabled to 'true' in the tutorial project.

The error I am getting is as follows:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer;
>   at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.ResponseBody.create(Unknown Source)
>   at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.Util.(Unknown Source)
>   at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Unknown Source) 
>   at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(Unknown Source)
>   at dji.thirdparty.okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "okio.Buffer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar",]] (With more
>   zip file references)

I'm using the proguard file DJI uses with their tutorial projects where I added some extra lines (https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-GEODemo/blob/master/GEODemo/app/proguard-rules.pro)

Everything points towards the proguard file, but I've run out of ideas, which is why I've come here for some assistance =)

Best Regards
KevinG

Answer (score 0):

I have been in contact with DJI, and they have provided me with an update that works.

They updated their proguard file with the following:

```
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
```

They changed org.boundcycastle from

```
-keep,allowshrinking class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
```

To what i wrote earlier. (But keeping both worked for me)

/Kevin